# The logic of field type in relationship

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have some tables for user preferences like `currency`, `language` and ...

`currency` structure and sample records :

```
id  |   title    |  slug
----+------------+--------
1   | US Dollar  | usd
2   | CA Dollar  | cad
3   | Euro       | eur
4   | Swiss Franc| chf
```

`language` structure and sample records :

```
id  |   title     |    code   |   flag
----+-------------+-----------+----------
1   | English     | en        | img/flags/en.png
2   | French      | fr        | img/flags/fr.png
```

I want create a relation between these tables and `users` tables, I want to know which field is better for foreign key ? for example in `currency` table `currency.id` or `currency.slug` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see **sql** speed than you should go for currency.id because finding **integer** value from lots so many rows (in thousands) **would be faster** then finding into **varchar**.

But here you see **currency won't be more then 500 so you can use both** it won't affect your speed.

you can use both in this particular example:
**currency.id or currency.slug**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, what's your idea about size ? because I should store `usd` for each user in `users` table instead of `1`

Comment: integer will always be **4 bytes**

Comment: integer will always be **4 bytes** but varchar is dynamic so it will calculate on your slug **1 byte per character* here slug looks small **3 char** so you can use currency.slug for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You to make relationship using currency.id. Relationship should be made using primary key For huge amount of data.